# Getting error $ operator not defined for this S4 class when findings mean of residuals

Tags: r, error-handling, mean

heyy i have a problem with getting the the below error. I am new to R and not sure how to resolve this!!

I am trying to find the mean of residuals in a multi-linear regression model (testing for the assumptions)

My code is

```
mean(model1$residuals)
```

where model1 is

```
model1 = lmer(corruption ~ Gini.Index + GDP + Democracy.Index + Political.Terror.Index + Economic.Freedom  + Regime + respondentage + 
            respondentgender + Education_Completed + Employment + European.Integration  + (1 | country), NewD, REML = FALSE)
```

When i run the code for mean i get error--- error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Does anyone know what to do???

Comment: You can use `mean(resid(model1))` - unlike `lm` objects, the `lmerMod` objects created by `lmer` are S4 objects which don't have members accessed by `$` - they have _slots_ accessed by `@`, but it's better to use the defined methods such as `resid` to get the data out that you need.

Comment: Heyyy thank youu soo much!!! it works now

Answer (score 1):

This is because `lmer` does not return a value of class "lm" as `lm` does. The return value of `lmer` (with which I am not familiar) has many slots. Slots in S4 classes are accessed using `@`. I suggest you try

```
str(model1)
```

and find the variable you need to access, e.g. like this

```
model1@resp$mu
```